# T-SQL Count all rows and group by id

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, average

i have a little problem with sql. 
I need help by a query where is can count all rows and group by the id.
I need this, because i need to get the average of logins.

Table have this: MRr, date

MNr 3 => 5 entries

MNr 4 => 2 entries

MNr 5 => 7 entries

And now i need to result all MNr with entries count more than 50% of all average.
Like: `(5+2+7)/3 = 4,666` and the result are MNr 3 and MNr 5.

I tried this with something like `AVG(COUNT(date))` but it doesnt work.

I hope you guys know what i mean... hard to explain for me sorry.

Greetz

Comment: Not clear what you are saying. Can you add some sample data and expected output, may be that will clear it up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An alternative solution:

```
select MRr, count(*) as _count
from mnr
group by MRr
having count(*) > (select count(*) / count(distinct mrr) * 1.0 from mnr)
```

Comment: I think you could use just 1 subquery in the having i.e. `(select count(*) / (count(distinct mrr) * 1.0) from mnr)`

Comment: this works for me. But for what your a multiple 1.0?

Comment: @R3Tech To force a conversion to a floating point number, as the result would have been rounded otherwise and the comparison would have been incorrect. It would have come out rounded as 4. In this particular case it might not have mattered though - but it would still be an error.

Answer (score 5):

You seem to want the MNR that have more than the average number of logins for an MNR.  Here is a method that uses window functions:

```
select mnr, cnt
from (select mnr, count(*) as cnt, avg(1.0*count(*)) over () as avg
      from table t
      group by mnr
     ) t
where cnt > avg;
```

Comment: Yes, but i dont ujnderstand so right your query? a query in a query? i never did this in the school atm so i dont think i need this for the answer.

Comment: If you want to learn the SQL language, you should learn all the components and how to use them correctly.